# Ubuntu: Environment variable is deleted after closing session

Tags: environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04

I am setting an environment variable in `Ubuntu 14.04` for a script to use it.

I opened the terminal and did:

```
export VARNAME=/home/me/folder/folder2
```

And then run the script and everything works fine. But anyway as soon as I close my session, the variable seems to disappear and I have to declare it again like the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you set the variable via terminal it will last till shutdown. If you want to set permanent variable you have to do the following.

```
    $ vi ~/.bash_proflle

    // set the variable in the file
```

exit by pressing esc key and type :wq Now the path is set.

Comment: my .bash_profile file is empty or non-existant and setting the parameter in there doesn't work either for me. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

To set an environment variable that doesn't get erased with the closing of the terminal (Ubuntu 16.04), follow these steps:

- Open `.bashrc` file by using the text editor of your choice. For me, it was
  `code ~/.bashrc` as I use VS Code, but you can use `vi ~/.bashrc` or `subl ~/.bashrc`.
- Add the environment variable using `export VARNAME=/home/me/folder/folder2`
- Save the file and close.

The variable will persist even after the terminal is closed.

Comment: Tried this but still doesn't work. (was in my /home/<user_profile>/.bashrc